# Why my tableview is slow?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

im making a tableview loaded with some NSArrays, the cell contains two labels and a background image view loaded with a URL image. The problem is that the scrolling of the tableview is slow, its like freeze or something.... i think that is because of the Imageview but what can i do???

heres some of my code so you can see:

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.


    return _Title.count;


}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    int row = [indexPath row];

    cell.TitleLabel.text = _Title[row];
    cell.DescriptionLabel.text = _content[row];
    cell.CellImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_ImageUrl[row]]]];
    cell.CellImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop;
    cell.CellImageView.contentMode = UIContentSizeCategoryMedium;

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];





    return cell;
}
```

For extra info this tableview presents a Detailviewcontroller with this same info.

Comment: Because you are trying to access each cell's image from the Internet. This is very bad for performance. Please see Apple's sample app named LazyTableImages for a proper solution.

Comment: `i think that is because of the Imageview but what can i do?` What you can do is comment out everything that has to do with the image view and see if the performance changes.  That'd be a good start.  rmaddy is right about the actual problem... I'm just making a point about proper debugging techniques.

Comment: There are multiple valid answers here that are being down voted for no reason.

Comment: I've up voted yours @morcutt. AFNetworking is an excellent framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are blocking the main thread with the following line of code:

```
cell.CellImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_ImageUrl[row]]]];
```

My suggestion would be to use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking) and replace the code with the following:

```
[cell.cellImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/image.png"]];
```

Also, your pointers should start with a lower case letter. For instance, CellImageView should be cellImageView.

Answer (score 5):

Load the image asynchronously(load it as the images come in). Look into great classes such as `SDWebImage` https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: Including a snippet of the relevant code (loading images in UITableViewCell's asynchronously) would be extremely helpful... and to be honest, it shouldn't be something you need to import a class from github to do for you... it's not complex in the least.

Comment: I've found that loading images into tableview cells is actually non trivial. When things like cell reuse come into play. I don't see any reason to reinvent the wheel and not use something like SDWebImage which is excellent.

Comment: Agreed. Plus SDWebImage adds cache and asynchronous downloading(individually, separate from image view )

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @vborra's answer - the reason why your tableview is slow is that (in your code) the entire image MUST have finished downloading before it displays.

This is because `dataWithContentsOfURL:` is a synchronous method. You need to use asynchronous APIs to download images in the background and when they've finished downloading, display them on the screen.

Here is a code snippet from the github page adapted for your example. Make sure you add the folder SDWebImage and it's contents from https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage to your project.

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

...

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    int row = [indexPath row];

    cell.TitleLabel.text = _Title[row];
    cell.DescriptionLabel.text = _content[row];
    [cell.CellImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_ImageUrl[row]]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    cell.CellImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop;
    cell.CellImageView.contentMode = UIContentSizeCategoryMedium;

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return cell;
}
```

Note, if you're downloading images of all different sizes, you may end up with resizing issues which will also decrease your performance. The SDWebImage page has a link to an article to help you with this problem if you come across it. http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2011/11/sdwebimage-fixed-width-cell-images/

You may also experience a performance bump when using transparency and tableviews, but it depends on the rest of your code.

AFNetworking is an excellent tool to use, but might be overkill if you're not using networking anywhere else in your app.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_ImageUrl[row]]]` from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` , which is not good idea. Because it'll go to the server every time a `UITableViewCell` is loaded.

You must use **Asynchronous** image loading & cache. These libraries might help you : (My personal favourite is `SDWebImage`)

1) https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

2) https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

And more, you can refer to the sample code by **Apple** about `LazyTableImages` - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

**UPDATE:**

For `SDWebImage` follow this guide. It's very good.

http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.in/2013/04/lazy-image-loading.html

Answer (score -2):

load your image like this

```
//get a dispatch queue
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
//this will start the image loading in bg
dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mapUrlStr]];
    //this will set the image when loading is finished
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.CellImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData]

    });
});
```

Comment: Loading code synchronously on a background queue is not a good technique for handling image loading from a URL as the queue is still blocked. If the user scrolls through 100 cells using your code, it will have to load them sequentially in order on a cell that still exists in memory, but may have been reused by the time the image has loaded.

Comment: SDWebImage used "dispatch_async" as well. So I'm actually not sure  if your solution so much better. But anyway I will take a deeep look in this topic and write a detailed "How to", soon. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: dispatch_async allows a block to run on a specified queue (DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT) so your code doesn't block the main thread. dispatch_async is good.

However, you're calling [NSURL URLWithString:mapUrlStr], which is a synchronous method. This means that it is a blocking method. It is not possible to cancel this method once it has started. It has the advantage of "looking like it's processing in the background" as the UI doesn't lock up, but it is definitely not efficient code as it is impossible to cancel the request and the requests will likely happen sequentially.